# How do I implement a version of Flutter's WidgetsBindingObserver without using state?

Tags: flutter

I am building a flutter app and I need to call a method in a provider when the app goes into background.

I can easily do this by creating a Stateful Widget using the WidgetsBindingObserver ([like the example here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html)).

Is there a way to do this without needing a Stateful Widget? Provider is a great architecture and state is an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly, You could try creating a class that isn't a widget and extending WidgetsBindingObserver.

Something like this perhaps

```
class MyListener extends  WidgetsBindingObserver {

    MyListener({this.providerInstance}){
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    };

    MyProvider providerInstance;
    @override
    void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
        providerInstance.doSomethingWithState(state)
    }
}
```

Then implement the listener say in main() or yourApp() where ever your Provider setup is.

Thing is, there really isn't any issue with having  a stateful widget at the root of your app somewhere as in the example. I honestly don't think your Anti pattern argument holds any relevance. Its common practice in flutter to have statefull and not statefull widgets.

By not having the statefull widget your just having to keep the state somewhere else, i.e. where ever it is your configuring your providers.